# jQuery element index

Tags: jquery

I have a table full of tabular data.  I need to find the index of a column(cell) in the table.

For example:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td>
<td>Column2</td>
<td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>foo</td>
<td>bar</td>
<td>foobar</td>
</tr>
</table>

function TestIndexOf(someTD)
{
$(someTD) // what's my column index?  
}
```

Comment: If you're not going use an id to access the column, what method are you going to use? In what context will you need to know the column index? This is important information for any potential solution.

Comment: It's actually a function that's going to pass the node into.  I've updated the code to reflect this better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$('td').prevAll().length` will give you the 0-based index of a cell

Alternatively using [`index()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/index) (can pass a DOM element or a jQuery object in. If jQuery object, only the first object in the wrapped set is used)

```
var cell = $('td'); // select on cell
cell.parent().index(cell);
```

If I recall correctly, `index()` will be easier to use in jQuery 1.4 and will allow you to simply call index() on the element wrapped in a jQuery object to get the index, like so

```
$('td').index() // NOTE: This will not work in versions of jQuery less than 1.4
```

So for your function

```
function TestIndexOf(someTD) {
    return $(someTD).prevAll().length; 
}
```

Comment: Perfect.  I actually searched for index in the jquery docs, but failed to find it.  Maybe I'm blind.  Thanks again.

Comment: I highly recommend downloading the documentation here - http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#Documentation under **API Reference**. Using the Search in the HTML files is far easier to navigate than the site.