# How to get the index of an <li> in a <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to get index of <li> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048718/how-to-get-index-of-li-element)
>   [jQuery - get the index of a element with a certain class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204349/jquery-get-the-index-of-a-element-with-a-certain-class)

I have:

```
<ul id="parent">
     <li id="li1">li1</li>
     <li id="li2">li2</li>
     <li id="li3">li3</li>
</ul>
```

There are some other `<ul>` and `<li>` tags elsewhere.

I want to get the index of **li2** which is in the `<ul>` with id **parent** using jQuery

Comment: Duplicate of _[How to get index of <li> element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048718/how-to-get-index-of-li-element)_, and _[Find the position of an element within a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046307/find-the-position-of-an-element-within-a-list), and [Get index of Element within UL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965825/get-index-of-element-within-ul)_, and _[Index of div element in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180542/index-of-div-element-jquery)_, and...

Comment: yeah, go back to your previous questions and click some checkmarks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - get the index of a element with a certain class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204349/jquery-get-the-index-of-a-element-with-a-certain-class) or [jQuery element index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663464/jquery-element-index)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**OLD**  simple answer: `$('ul#parent li:eq(1)').index()`

**NEW** `$('#li2').index()`

Comment: This answer assumes you know the index before trying to get the index.

Comment: That is somehow redundant (in a one level list). You are accessing the second `li` element(`li:eq(1)`) to get its index which will be `1` too.

Comment: @jessegavin No it doesn't; it's only an example of requesting any particular element, but then asking for its index.

Comment: new: works. @Pixel bobby thanks alot. i was struggling for last1 hr

Comment: What exactly is mean by `OLD` and `NEW`? Is it _Obsolete_, _Deprecated_ or what? Thank You..

Answer (score 12):

Use [**`.index()`**](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

```
$('#li2').index();
```

IDs have to be unique so in case they are not in your HTML, you better fix this (e.g. by using classes).

Comment: -1 This question has been asked and answered repeatedly. Felix, you don't need more rep (OK, we all need more rep :) but closing as a duplicate is more beneficial to the site than re-answering a common question.

Comment: @Phrogz: You are right, the questions are all very similar but the context is always a bit different. However I found a question that is very close to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204349/jquery-get-the-index-of-a-element-with-a-certain-class

Comment: What I think is different, If the question is closed because of Duplicate policy its okay, but if the question is open for answers, and if the question is answered but not accepted by the User. It means user is expecting more and what has been answered doesn't work for him/her. That way SO will have some other approaches for solving similar problem. You may disagree. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

```
var index = $("#li2").prevAll().length;  //assuming 0 based index
```