# jQM: getting index of active page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

If I have a structure like this:

```
<body>
 <div data-role="page" data-dom-cache="true" id="foo">...</div>
 <div data-role="page" data-dom-cache="true" id="bar">...</div>
 <div data-role="page" data-dom-cache="true" id="baz">...</div>
</body>
```

How do I get the position of bar in this series of divs? It should return 2 in this case.

I'm using this to try to get the index of the current page in jquery mobile. Right now I'm doing:

```
$( '#<%=@page_id%>' ).bind( 'pageshow',function(event){
    alert('current page = '+$.mobile.activePage.index())
})
```

But this is showing me index=1 for the 1st page, index=3 for the 2nd page and from there it increases linearly to 4,5...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the index of an <li> in a <ul>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914110/how-to-get-the-index-of-an-li-in-a-ul)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `index()`:

```
var index = $('#bar').index();
```

Which will return the index position of the element among its sibling elements, or you can pass a selector:

```
var index = $('#bar').index(selector);
```

Wherein jQuery will return the index position of `$('#bar')` among the matched elements returned by the selector passed to index.

Note that JavaScript works with zero-based arrays; so the above (in the first) will return `1` (not `2`). If you must have `2` then remember to explicitly `+ 1`:

```
var index = $('#bar').index() + 1;
```

But, when using that `index` variable (perhaps with `eq()`) remember to adjust for that addition, otherwise things may break unexpectedly. Or, at least, work differently.

References:

- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).

Comment: Add one to the zero-based `index`, for the OP's circumstances.

Comment: Thanks, I shouldve been more specific with the problem I was having. The second statement you provided solved my problems, I guess I was selecting EVERYTHING under body and not just the pages.