# How to know the exact children number of Ul element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a newbie in web development. Not sure if it is a dumb question.

```
<nav class="navigation">
    <ul class="navigation-items-container">
      <a href="#"><li class="navigation-items">Home</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li class="navigation-items">about</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li class="navigation-items">blog</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li class="navigation-items">contacts</li></a>
    </ul>
/nav>
```

On hover of each li I want to know its in which children Number of ul.
i.e
On hovering "Home" it should give as children Number 0 and on hovering "blog" it should give children number 2.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The anchors should be enclosed by the li, not the other way round.

Comment: thanks everyone . I will correct the HTML.

Answer (score 7):

As you've included the jQuery tag I'll post a jQuery based answer - if you want a non-jQuery answer let me know:

```
$(".navigation-items-container li").hover(function(e) {
    var index = $(this).index();
});
```

And FYI your markup is wrong, the anchors should be inside the `li` tags

The version for your current code (though it should be changed):

```
$(".navigation-items-container a").hover(function(e) {
    var index = $(this).index();
});
```

Comment: While I agree the OP should change their markup, this answer is technically incorrect as it stands.

Comment: @musefan I've added a new version with a different selector to match their current markup

Answer (score 1):

Due to the fact that your `li` elements are within `a` elements, you should use this:

```
$(".navigation li").hover(function(){
    var index = $(".navigation li").index(this);
    alert(index);
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/rJJa9/)

---

Of course, it would be better to have your `a` elements with the `li` elements like so:

```
<li class="navigation-items"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
```

That way the `li` elements will be direct children of the `ul` element, then you could do this:

```
$(".navigation li").hover(function(){
    var index = $(this).index();
    alert(index);
});
```

[Here is a better example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/rJJa9/1/)

---

Alternatively, and I am not saying this is better, but you could also use `data-*` attributes to store the value you want:

```
<li class="navigation-items" data-myindex="0"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
```

with this:

```
$(".navigation li").hover(function(){
    var index = $(this).data("myindex");
    alert(index);
});
```

This has the benefit that you could specify different values if required, such as record IDs for example.

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/rJJa9/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try  [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

http://api.jquery.com/index/

```
  $(".navigation ul li").hover(function(e) {
   alert($(this).index());
});
```

[More possiblities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914110/how-to-get-the-index-of-an-li-in-a-ul)

Answer (score 0):

this help you

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/7SmfR/

```
$(".navigation ul li").hover(function() {
    alert($(this).index('li'));
});
```

Correct your markup anchor(`a`) tag should be enclosed within `li` tags

```
<nav class="navigation">
    <ul class="navigation-items-container">
        <li class="navigation-items">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navigation-items">
            <a href="#">about</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navigation-items">
            <a href="#">blog</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navigation-items">
            <a href="#">contacts</a>
        </li>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('li').on('mouseover', function(){
    console.log($('ul li').index($(this)));
})
```